# How to run specific tests with Karma?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

**Problem**,
I have a huge project with many tests that are redundant, and some not. So i need to be able to run specific tests that predefined by a config file or a simple variable that contains a list of files (all got different path).

So for example, what i wish to achieve is the following :

- Here is the test.ts that's included by tsconfig.json

  ```
    import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import {
      BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      platformBrowserDynamicTesting,
    } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

    declare const __karma__: any;
    declare const require: any;

    __karma__.loaded = function () {};

    getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
      BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
    );

    const tests = ['users.service', 'login.service', 'user.component'];
    // This is more or less what i had in mind
    tests.forEach((TEST_FILE_NAME)=>{
    //const context = require.context('./', true, /users\.service\.spec\.ts/);
    const context = require.context('./', true, /TEST_FILE_NAME\.spec\.ts/);
    context.keys().map(context);
    })

    __karma__.start();
  ```

I know i can simply concat the files with OR operator, but i'm looking for a maintainable friendly way to do so:

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /users\.service\.spec.ts|login\.service\.spec\.ts|user\.component\.spec\.ts/);
```